# How to select rows where an attribute can have two values

Tags: sql

I have a table called site_attributes which looks similar to this:

```
siteId     attributeId     tier
-------------------------------
site1id    attribute1id    1
site1id    attribute2id    1
site1id    attribute3id    1
```

How can I select from the table the unique site id where attributeId is equal to attribute1id AND attributeId is equal to attribute3id?

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT siteId, count(*) ct
FROM TableName
WHERE attributeId IN ('attribute1id', 'attribute3id')
GROUP BY siteId
HAVING ct = 2
```

or

```
SELECT t1.siteId
FROM TableName t1
JOIN TableName t2 USING (siteId)
WHERE t1.attributeId = 'attribute1id'
AND t2.attributeId = 'attribute3id'
```

Comment: Your first query might not work correctly if site1id has 2 attributeId with the same value. That is, if attribute3id was attribute1id it would still output site1id which is not what the user wants. However, your 2nd query should produce correct results.

Comment: @Ahmedov Typically, relation tables like this are designed with `(siteId, attributeId)` being a unique, composite key, and I was making that simplifying assumption. And it's likely to be more efficient than a join.